# What is the best augmented reality SDK that supports Android to use for monuments detection and recognition in a museum?

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm new to AR and there seems to be many SDKs for Android and I don't which is best to use and which ones to avoid.

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with using Vuforia through Unity3d: https://www.vuforia.com/Features

It's pretty easy to setup and use if you're familiar with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify exactly what are your needs, what are the detection characteristics, and what is your dilemma.

But I'll try to help anyway. For example - do the monuments have enough graphical features to be detected? can you add some marking of your own to (or near to) the monument, in case the answer to the previous question is no? Will it be commercial (licensing and payment are to be considered)? do you need geo-location (outdoor or in-door)? what platforms do you need to support?

Once you know your needs, there are a lot of comparison articles for AR SDKs, but you need to choose what's relevant for your specifications. This is one for example: [Augmented Reality SDK Comparison](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks)